# Css issues with ui-view

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to put my side-navbar and header into a `ui-view` and then my side-navbar looses some styling as it seems. I don't undestand why, since the **HTML** is the same, other that the use of the `ui-view` directive.

```
   <body data-ng-app="app" id="app" class="app" data-custom-page data-ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <div id="loader-container"></div>
    <header ng-include=" 'client/app/layout/header.html' " id="header" class="header-container "></header>
    <div class="main-container">
        <aside data-ng-include=" 'client/app/layout/sidebar.html' " id="nav-container" class="nav-container"></aside>
        <div id="content" class="content-container">
            <section data-ui-view class="view-container {{main.pageTransition.class}}"></section>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When the code for the sidebar and header are in the **index.html**, it looks fine. But when i move it to a separate **HTML file** and uses the ui-view, the site bare then becomes horizontal

```
<body data-ng-app="app" id="app" class="app" data-custom-page data-ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <div id="loader-container"></div>
    <ui-view></ui-view>   <-- renders the same code as above
```

Comment: Have you compared the rendered html, maybe you are getting different result depending on if you rendering it as separate view. Use dev tool in chrome and compare the rendered html.

Comment: Try to write dynamic css classes with ng-class